# In praise of "... and links therein"

Tags: discussion, moderators, users

We've all seen them: short comments saying

```
Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/..., and links therein.
```

Also, we've all seen bunches of useful links to closely-related questions on the `Linked` sidebar over on the right, which are a very useful way to navigate the site. Also, you know what's useful for navigating the site? Correctly-tagged posts.

Some of that happens by itself, but mostly it requires active attention and maintenance, and while we all do our equal share, some users have more equal shares than others in this game. I've been keeping my eye on some of the stats, and we just passed a milestone I would like not to go by unmarked.

- A single user is responsible for [over <s>3000</s> <s>4000</s> <s>(just under) 5000</s> 7000 comments of the form "Related:..." or "...therein"](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/382526/qmechanics-amazing-post-linking-comments).
- For comparison, [the next user down has <s>150</s> <s>200</s> <s>250</s> 490 such comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/433533/users-by-related-and-therein-links-in-comments).
- Freeing the query from that particular form, this user has [<s>4500</s> <s>5500</s> <s>6750</s> 9700 comments that include an in-site link, to < <s>1.4k</s> <s>1.8k</s> 2.3k by the next user down](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/433534/users-by-in-site-links-in-comments).
- This user also has [<s>eleven</s> <s>sixteen</s> <s>twenty-two</s> forty-five times more tag edits than the next most prolific tag editor](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/433535/users-by-number-of-tag-edits), at the completely mind-boggling count of <s>19,920</s> <s>30,177</s> <s>43,117</s> 85,904 such edits, to <s>1815</s> <s>1876</s> 1911 by the next user down.

All of this has a very definite, very positive impact on the site.

We all know who you are. Thank you.

Comment: "We all know who you are" -- except all we really know are "theoretical physicist" and "Europe," both of which could be misdirection ;)

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes. Also - and I just want to remark on this - we have no gender information. So the rule of thumb is don't assume.

Comment: Seriously, though, phenomenal contribution. Thanks indeed.

Comment: Thanks Emilio and everyone for the kind praise!

Comment: @Qmechanic What a rarity - I think this is the first personal comment I've ever seen from you :) Thanks for your contributions :P

Comment: @Qmechanic And in all this time, to have still never once asked a question of your own. I just find that fascinating.

Comment: @LoganJ.Fisher Mechanics don't need to go to the garage?? 