# Qmechanic reaches 100k rep

Tags: discussion, reputation

Please join me in congratulating @Qmechanic upon reaching the 100k rep milestone.  We can all agree that his/her contribution to this site has been nothing short of outstanding, and the recognition that comes with 100k rep is absolutely well deserved.

Edit: as pointed out by @ACuriousMind, there is an [appropriate laudatio](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/in-praise-of-and-links-therein) by @EmilioPisanty which deserves to be highlighted in the main post beyond just a comment.

Comment: Don't forget his contributions that yield no reputation at all, cf. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7508/50583 and links therein!

Comment: @ACuriousMind selfless effort with moderating...  the list of important contributions is long... and always the same level of professionalism.

Comment: Awesome! Congrats!!

Comment: Congratulations, @Qmechanic !  Your answers are magnificent, and your style is inspiring.

Comment: I'm going to wait for Q's comment here...

Comment: Congratulations, @Qmechanic !

Comment: Thanks for your amazing contribution, congratulations.

Comment: I totally agree! Qmechanic's amazing! I would feel a little wierd upvoting someones reputation to congratulate someone else though. (no offense meant ZeroTheHero )  I'm going to go look at some of Qmechanic's wonderful answers!!

Comment: @R.Rankin Meta sites don't have reputation. Upvotes and downvotes here don't change it.

Comment: @Chair         OH! I've never spent time on the metas, Thanks!! (:

Comment: Congratulations. I am still very new to the site, but I can tell that there is a lot of selfless effort to help people with their understanding, and there is some high calibre technical discussion as well as lovely examples of teaching for the high school learners and clarification for general public. Clearly Qmechanic has made a huge contribution to making this a site of lasting value and growing significance.

Comment: Hat's off and chilled beer to Qmechanic!  Amazing!  Just wow!  And it's weird to give more reputations to guys giving reputations to Qmechanic!

Comment: @Cham see comment by Chair $\uparrow$.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! Thanks for the nice words!

Comment: Congratulations @Qmechanic, and thanks for the great contribution. A lot of people (myself included) certainly have learned a lot of Physics from you.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks :)

Comment: I'm so curious as to who @Qmechanic is in 'real life'! Will you lift the mask??

Comment: yay @Qmechanic good job

Comment: @Qmechanic I appreciate everything you do