# Can anyone advice the real name of "Qmechanic"?

Tags: discussion

I am a big fan of the rigidity, depth and straightforwardness of "Qmechanic" answers, I wonder if he\she has a book\notes in some fields of physics, I believe we can learn much faster by using them.

So I wonder if we can know his real name (if that allowed by StackExchange or he\she has willingness).

Comment: Vaguely related: [In praise of “… and links therein”](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/in-praise-of-and-links-therein).

Comment: Regarding that last line (in V1), Stack Exchange allows people to reveal their real names (you'll notice the number of people who either mention their name in their about me or use their names as user names. The topic of anonymity has been discussed quite a bit, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40217

Answer (score 21):

Over the course of his/her participation on this site, Qmechanic has made it consistently clear that they wish to remain pseudonymous and s/he has not mentioned any information (to my knowledge, at least - but I've been here a long time) that could be used to identify him/her.

It is important that we respect this attitude: you can of course ask him/her directly, in a polite fashion, but this is not public information and it should not be made public without Qmechanic's explicit consent.

Comment: It may be worth stressing that this is of course not specific to Qmechanic: *Any* user has the right to remain anonymous, and beyond possibly asking politely **once** for a user's real name other users should simply respect that by not bothering them about it..

Comment: Yeah, anonymity is preferred for many of us.